# How to get feeds of facebook using simple facebook?

Tags: android-simple-facebook

I am trying to get all the feeds of facebook id. I got all the feeds using graph explorer tools but when I use simple facebook 2.0 in android, I didn't get all feeds but few.

```
   `String entityId = "me";
    String edge = "feed";
    //Bundle params = new Bundle();
    //params.putString("fields", "feed");
    simpleFacebook.get(entityId, edge, null, onActionListener);`
```

Above code is my part of simple facebook code.

I want the result that is similar to the result of ***me?fields=feed***. How can I get the result? I don't want to use facebook SDK 3.15.0.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getPosts()` method:

```
String entityId = ...;
mSimpleFacebook.getPosts(entityId, PostType.ALL, onPostsListener);
```

You can filter by:

- **`PostType.ALL`** - Everything that was published (links, statuses, photos...) that appears on the users' wall. (uses graph path: *`{entityId}/feed`)
- **`PostType.LINKS`** - Link published by the entity. (uses graph path: *`{entityId}/links`*)
- **`PostType.POSTS`** - Posts published by the entity. (uses graph path: *`{entityId}/posts`*)
- **`PostType.STATUSES`** - Status update posts published by the entity. (uses graph path: *`{entityId}/statuses`*)
- **`PostType.TAGGED`** - Posts in which the person is tagged. (uses graph path: *`{entityId}/tagged`*)

Comment: It does more than I did last time but I am still not able to get friend's status and comments. What is the procedure?